# Why different sequence is observed for same SQL query on different DBMS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle

How does `ORDER BY` work when there are multiple rows with the same name?
I executed a query:

```
SELECT * FROM XYZ ORDER BY NAME;
```

On Oracle I get the following result:

| Name | Uid | OwnerId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Test123 | QuuNWWzUJKmZPC | iotNmQNGJKmZPC |
| Test123 | NULL | NULL |

On SQL Server I get the following result

| Name | Uid | OwnerId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Test123 | NULL | NULL |
| Test123 | QuuNWWzUJKmZPC | iotNmQNGJKmZPC |

Why is a different sequence shown? In Oracle the row with `NULL` appears 2nd whereas in SQL Server it appeared 1st. Is there any default behavior for each DBMS?

Is there any way to make SQL Server's result look like Oracle's?

Comment: For "ties" the order is arbitrary. *"is there any way to make MSSQL result look like Oracle?"* Yes, use an `ORDER BY` that doesn't result in ties, and so *every value* is assigned a unique position.

Comment: You get exactly what you ask for (via `ORDER BY`) and nothing further is guaranteed, with regards to ordering of the results.

Comment: To further add to my comment, your statement (`SELECT * FROM XYZ ORDER BY NAME;`) could actually end up returning the results in a different order *every time* you run it. When the ordering is arbitrary there are *a lot* of things that can affect what that arbitrary order is.

Comment: No, there's no default order. Add another column to the `ORDER BY` if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An unordered result set is delivered with a non-deterministic ordering and it is possible that the order can change with every execution of the query.

If you apply an `ORDER BY` clause that defines a total ordering of the result set then that result set will be delivered in a deterministic ordering and the output will be identical with every execution of the query (assuming the underlying data set is unchanged).

If you apply an `ORDER BY` clause that defines a partial ordering of the result set then the results set will be partly ordered and partly non-deterministic.

For example, if you have the data set:

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | 1 |
| Beryl | 2 |
| Beryl | 3 |
| Alice | 4 |
| Alice | 5 |
| Beryl | 6 |

and you use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
ORDER BY name, value
```

Then that defines a total ordering of the result set such that it will be initially ordered by name, which defines a partial ordering, and then, within each set of rows with the same name, will be ordered by the value and the values are unique. This outputs:

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | 1 |
| Alice | 4 |
| Alice | 5 |
| Beryl | 2 |
| Beryl | 3 |
| Beryl | 6 |

If you do not define a total ordering:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
ORDER BY name
```

Then the rows will be ordered by `name` but within the set of rows with the same names the individual rows can be in **ANY** order and this is a partial order and could output:

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | 5 |
| Alice | 4 |
| Alice | 1 |
| Beryl | 3 |
| Beryl | 6 |
| Beryl | 2 |

but equally could output:

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | 5 |
| Alice | 1 |
| Alice | 4 |
| Beryl | 6 |
| Beryl | 2 |
| Beryl | 3 |

> Is there any way to make SQL Server's result look like Oracle's?

Do not apply a partial ordering; add columns to your `ORDER BY` clause to make it a total ordering and then the RDBMSes should output the result set in the same order.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   XYZ
ORDER BY
       NAME ASC,
       UID  ASC NULLS LAST;
```

Comment: A good answer. The `NULLS LAST` clause is standard SQL and available in Oracle, but not yet featured in SQL Server, as far as I know.